# How do you launch a nuke in Fallout 76?

Tags: fallout-76

What is the step by step procedure to launch a nuke in FO76?
I know you need launch codes and have to go to a silo to initiate a launch, but

- How many codes do you need?
- Where can you get the codes?
- How to initiate the launch?

Comment: You're probably getting downvoted because it's obvious you did not try even a basic internet search. People like to help people who try to help themselves.

Comment: @TimS. I know why I am getting downvoted &I did do an google search,.. after I looked here & saw how "dead" this section of Arqada was  Just because the answer is already online doesn't mean its a bad question. Its probably one of the most googled question for Fallout 76 but Arqada doesnt have it in its list. For a game that was such a hype, its kind of a shame to see such low activity on Arqada while every do-it-yourself-blog has a half a** guide or a link to a youtube video for it. All of those are aimed at generating traffic for the  advertisments  on their site instead of quality answers

Comment: I agree that it's a shame to see a popular game get no love here. In that case, it's perfectly acceptable to ask a question and answer it yourself for the purpose of providing the information to others. Plenty of people have done that in the past. To leave an unanswered question like that generally tells people that you didn't do the research, not that you were trying to foster discussion or generate useful knowledge.  Just trying to help.

Comment: @TimS. I was planning on adding my own answer, after i had actually done this myself once ingame. I dont want to just copy a guide and paste it here, just so we would get the traffic. I also feel this situation is becoming more common here. I posted a question for BFV which got 0 attention, while that same question for BF3 or 4 would/ did get plenty of answers and input. Either way, i'm not planning on deleting my question. I hope people will add the relevant answers and that in the future, googlers will find that answer and be helped with.

Comment: @Vahx the site is called 'Arqade'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The steps required to launch a nuke in Fallout 76 are as follows:

- You must join 'The Enclave' in order to gain access to the Whitespring Bunker
- Complete both the 'Back to Basic' and 'Officer on Deck' missions to gain access to the Whitespring Bunker Command Center
- You must then head inside Whitespring Bunker which will start the 'I am become Death' mission.
- Then you must acquire a Nuclear Keycard. You can get these by shooting down a Cargobot and picking the lock of the Secure Transport Container. You can find cargobots at random locations throughout the map, but the location of one should be added to your map when you start the mission.
- Once you have the Keycard, get eight letter and number and combinations from high level Scorched or Feral Ghoul officers. The codes look like this:

[image: Nuclear Codes]

The locations of the ghoul officers can be found on a terminal in the Enclave Command Centre at the Whitespring Bunker on a terminal.

- Once you have your Keycard and 8 Launch Codes you need to decode the launch codes.
  The most simple way to do this is probably to get the launch codes from reddit (as the launch codes are the same for everyone, though they change every week), use a [decrypter](https://nukacrypt.com/), or use this [step by step guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo76/comments/9ygyy9/stepbystep_guide_to_decrypting_launch_codes/) which appears to have gotten a good response. (To decrypt the codes yourself I believe you have to head to the corresponding silo so see the next step)
- Now head to the corresponding silo. There are five steps for you to follow in the silo:

  - Step 1

    - Acquire a biometric card ID
    - Find an  old biometric ID card
    - Erase the old biometric ID Card
    - Acquire your Biometric Data
    - Create your biometric ID Card
    - Register your biometric ID Card
  - Step 2

    - Head for the control room
    - Access the terminal to shut down the reactors
    - Repair all of the leaking pipes
    - Restart the Reactor
  - Step 3

    - Destroy the Mainframe Cores
  - Step 4

    - Head for the control room
    - Replace the Mainframe cores
    - Open the Security Door
  - Step 5

    - Head for the Control Room
    - Initiate the launch prep
    - Complete the launch prep
    - Defend the Section Chiefs
    - Insert your nuclear keycard into the INSERT KEYCARD here machine
    - Insert your code into the Launch Code Entry Panel
    - Pick your target
    - Launch the Nuke

Enjoy the view!

Sources:

https://www.reddit.com/r/fo76/comments/9ygyy9/stepbystep_guide_to_decrypting_launch_codes/

https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2018-12-21-fallout-76-nuke-codes-launch-codes-5076

https://nukacrypt.com/

https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/game/launch-nukes-in-fallout-76-3687092/

https://gameranx.com/features/id/165511/article/fallout-76-how-to-launch-nukes-nuclear-silo-launch-codes-guide/

Comment: It can probably be noted that in order to replace Mainframe cores, you can either find them around (but they can be difficult to spot) or you can repair the ones you broke by taking them out and repairing at the Tinker terminal in next room -- but you need 2 circuitry and 3 steel for each repair (It was 16 cores or so total, afai remember).